# Reactjs - Loading big data async causes bad lighthouse performance rating

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I have an issue with our website. It is loading a big amount of data in an async `useEffect` hook. Now I've recognized that this big amount of data load is causing a bad performance rating in Google Lighthouse.
I'm really wondering, why this is causing a bad rating, because I'm loading the data in an async function and the complete component is being loaded with `lazy` and `Suspense`.
Why is this causing a bad rating respectively what can I do differently to avoid this bad rating?
The data which is being loaded async are exhibition data with an image of the exhibition in base64 format. That is why the data load is big.

The data is being loaded in the `MeetUs` component, this component is being loaded by `MainPage`:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
...

const MeetUs = React.lazy(() => import('./MeetUs.container.js'));

function MainPage(props) {
    return (
        <>
            ...
            <React.Suspense fallback={<div></div>}>
                <MeetUs 
                    key="meetUs" 
                    currentLanguage={props.currentLanguage}
                />
            </React.Suspense>
        </>
    );
}

export default MainPage;
```

This is the code of `MeetUs`:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
...
const Exhibition = React.lazy(() => import('./Exhibition.component'));
...

function MeetUs(props) {
    const [exhibitions, setExhibitions] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadExhibitions() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                window.axios.post(window.location.origin + '/company/exhibitions', {
                    requestType: 'getExhibitions'
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    if(response.data?.success) {
                        resolve(response.data.exhibitions);
                    }
                    else {
                        reject({error: 'Not successful'});
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);
                });
            });
        }

        loadExhibitions()
        .then((exhibitions) => {
            setExhibitions(exhibitions);
        })
        .then(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
    },[]);  

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid marginTop50px">
            ...
            {
                exhibitions.map((exhibition, index) => {
                    return (
                        <React.Suspense fallback={<div></div>}>
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <ExhibitionDiv>
                                    <Exhibition/>
                                </ExhibitionDiv>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        </React.Suspense>
                    )
                })
            }
            ...
        </div>
    );
}

export default MeetUs;
```

Answer (score 0):

While waiting, make sure that you will return a skeleton component that resembles the final output either on `<Suspense/>` or on `<MeetUs/>`. Even YouTube does it while on slow network.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the comment. That's I've already recognized, too. But it does not solve the performance issue, doesn't it?

Comment: ... and the difficulty is that I do not know how many exhibitions will be returned by the request. So it is hard to create a skeleton. Or I need to request first how many exhibitions without data, but that's not optimal.

Comment: Just display the default limit size for instance if you display 10 exhibition per page then display 10 skeleton of rows.